# How to stop audio inside a sweetalert?

Tags: javascript, html

With this code the button shows the alert and starts the song, but how does the sound stop when clicking the cancel button?

```js
document.querySelector(".first").addEventListener("click", function() {
  swal({
    title: "Show Two Buttons Inside the Alert",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
    confirmButtonColor: "#00ff99",
    cancelButtonColor: "#ff0099"
  });
});
```

```html
    <a id="footer-buttons" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm first" onclick="playAudio()"><span class="fa fa-music"></span> MUSICA</a>
```

Comment: Great this worked for you! Please note that I ported the code to sweetaudio version 2 (I had mixed the syntax of v1 and v2 in my initial answer) so you should use the updated code instead of the previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SweetAlert [uses Promises](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises) to check how a user interacted with the alert. In case an alert is dismissed via cancel click, the Promise will be resolved with `null` as parameter value. My below example shows how you could control the audio based on the user's choice.

```js
let aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
function swalFnc() {

  aud.play();

  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    buttons: {
      cancel: {
        visible: true,
        text: 'No, cancel plx!'
      },
      confirm: {
       visible: true,
        text: 'Yes, delete it!',
        className: 'swal-warning'
      }
    }
  }).then(function(isConfirmed) {
    if (isConfirmed === null) {
      aud.pause();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.swal-warning {
  background-color: #DD6B55;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="swalFnc()">
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_OOG_5MG.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another very elegant way by placing a PLAY / STOP button.

See here how it works on this page ... But you have to click on the "MUSICA" orange button: https://www.clubesorte.org/temas/1.tema-teste/

[image: This alert has the close button and with another button we can immediately hear the music, stop and return to the beginning.]

```js
<script>
/* Alert - patrocinio da musica  */ 
document.querySelector(".third").addEventListener("click", function() {
  swal({
    title: "Willie Nelson",
       html:
    'Música patrocinada por ' +
    '<a target="_blank" href="http://willienelson.com/">Willie Nelson</a> ' + '<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" style="font-family:inherit;font-size:13px;color:#fff;border:none;" onClick="play()">Play/Pause</a> ',
    
    imageUrl: "https://texashillcountry.com/wp-content/uploads/stage-660x400.jpg",
    imageWidth: 550,
    imageHeight: 225,
    imageAlt: "Eagle Image",
    showCancelButton: false,
    confirmButtonText: "Fechar", 
    cancelButtonText: "Stop",
    confirmButtonColor: "#428bca",
    cancelButtonColor: "#428bca",
    reverseButtons: true,
  });
});
</script>

<script>
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }else{
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<button id="footer-buttons" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm third"><span class="fa fa-music"></span> MUSICA</button>

<audio id="audio" controls tabindex="0" loop>
    <source type="audio/mp3" src="./img/willie-nelson-on-the-road-again.mp3">
    Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio. </audio>
```